# Fortran formatted IO and the Null character

Tags: fortran

I wonder how Fortran's I/O is expected to behave in case of a NULL character `ACHAR(0)`.

The actual task is to fill an ASCII file by blocks of precisely eight characters. The strings are read from a binary and may contain non-printing characters.

I tried with `gfortran` 4.8, 8.1 and `f2c`. If there is a NULL character in the string the format specifier `FORMAT(A8)` does **not** write eight characters.

Give the following F77 code a try:

```
c Print a string of eight character surrounded by dashes
100   FORMAT('-',A8,'-')
c Works fine if empty or any other combination of printing chars
      write(*,100) ''
c In case of a short sting blanks are padded
      write(*,100) '345678'
c A NULL character does something I did not expect
      write(*,100) '123'//ACHAR(0)//'4567'
c Not even position editing helps
101   FORMAT('-',A8,T10,'x')
      write(*,101) '123'//ACHAR(0)//'4567'
      end
```

My output is:

```
-        -
-  345678-
-1234567-
-1234567x
```

Is this expected behavior? Any idea how to get the output eight characters wide in any case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using an edit descriptor `A8` the field width is eight.  For output, eight characters will be written.

In the case of the example, it isn't the writing of the characters that is contrary to your expectations, but how they are displayed by your terminal.

You can examine the output further with tools like `hexdump` or you can write to an internal file and look at arbitrary substrings.

Comment: The terminal was fooling me, my bad. Indeed, `ACHAR(0)` is there. E.g. `./a.out | less` shows `^@`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that is expected, if there is a null character, the printing of the string *on the screen* can stop there. The characters will still be sent, but the string does not have to be printed on the screen.

Note that C uses NULL to delimit strings and the OS may interpret the strings it receives with the same conventions. The allows the non-printable characters to be interpreted in processor specific ways by the processor and the processor includes the whole complex of the compiler, the executing environment (OS and programs in the OS) and the hardware.

Comment: I suspect it's more likely that the runtime has output with the character and it's up to the terminal (or whatever) to display it however it chooses.

Comment: Yes, I think the same. One can do various things with control sequences like deleting a line, backspacing, moving up and down and so on. I probably used wrong words though. After all, a processor is the whole complex of compiler and the computer.

Comment: Indeed, my comment was more addressing the "printing of the string can stop there" part.  If the C library were stopping on reaching the null-termination point I'd expect output to be `-123`, or `-123     `, or such.  But that would be horribly broken.